# How to detect browser or tab close in Node/Express Application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, browser, backend

I'm currently working on this Node + Express MVC application and would like to shut off the Express server when the browser or tab gets closed. I know I can do this within a vanilla js script tag using the 'beforeunload' event listener on the window but then I wouldn't know how to send that information back to Express. Does anyone have a workaround or anyone know a package I can use? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a http request in beforeunload event handler via Web Worker. A web worker could run separate thread instead of main thread of javascript. So you can easily make a http request to server with information.

```
const beforeUnloadListener = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
   // You web worker should be here.
   // in case of true return you tab will close 
   // return true
};
```

This is a link of WebWorker.
https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-web-workers/?utm_campaign=1101742&utm_source=sendpulse&utm_medium=push

I hope it will help you. Thankyou